# C# simplest trace or log

Tags: c#, logging, trace

What is the simplest way to do a trace or log in C# windows form application?

Doesn't have to save to file, can be showing at runtime.
What would be the simplest thing to implement?

thanks

Comment: Probably best creating a text file with whatever you want to log

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using one of the following methods:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Something")
```

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Something")
```

Comment: If you are debugging, you can see the results in the Output window.

Comment: You can also use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) to view the traces with Trace.WriteLine

Answer (score 3):

You may checkout the [Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Trace class and add trace listener to store it in file.

Also take a look at Debug class.

Answer (score 1):

[System.Diagnostics.Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx)

Output is configurable in config file.